# nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

When I retrieve the entity object using JPA, it is getting "nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property". I have added property called nullable true also.

```
@Column(name="lat",nullable = true)
private double lat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `nullable` primitive type, that's a contradiction (in Java, at least). 
If you want lat to be `nullable`, you need to use the `Double` java type, not `double`

Comment: Thanks Thusitha. This is working for me as expected.